# No feasible entries for infix operator "=" [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have been writing the state machine for a traffic light controller.

```
-- Ampelsteuerung mit Zähler und FSM Componente

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity AMPLSTRG is 
    port (  CLK, B1, RES : in bit;
            MAINRE, MAINYE, MAINGR : out bit;
            FARMRE, FARMYE, FARMGR : out bit);
end AMPLSTRG;

architecture FUNKTION of AMPLSTRG is
type AMP_STATE is (S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8); -- Typendefinition
signal SCLR : bit;
signal CYCLES : unsigned (4 downto 0);
signal STATE, NEXT_STATE : AMP_STATE;                   -- STATE = aktueller Status, NEXT_STATE nächster Status (Typenzuweisung)
begin
-- COUNTER Prozess
CO: process (CLK)
begin
    if CLK = '1' and CLK'event then
        if SCLR = '1' then
            CYCLES <= (others => '0');                  -- 'others' = gesamten Vektor auf '0' setzten
        else
            CYCLES <= CYCLES + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process CO;

AMP_SYNC: process (CLK, RES)
begin
    if RES = '1' then
        STATE <= S0 after 5 ns;
        SCLR <= '1' after 5 ns;
    elsif CLK = '1' and CLK'event then
        STATE <= NEXT_STATE after 5 ns;                 -- Zustandszuweisung
    end if;
end process AMP_SYNC;

AMP_KOMB: process (STATE, B1, CYCLES)
begin
    -- default Werte Setzen
    MAINRE <= '0' after 5 ns; 
    MAINYE <= '0' after 5 ns;
    MAINGR <= '0' after 5 ns;

    FARMRE <= '0' after 5 ns; 
    FARMYE <= '0' after 5 ns; 
    FARMGR <= '0' after 5 ns;

    NEXT_STATE <= STATE; 
    SCLR <= '0';

    case STATE is
        when S0 => if B1 = '1' then 
                        MAINGR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        NEXT_STATE <= S1 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                    else                                -- MAINGR | FARMRE until B1 pressed
                        MAINGR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                   end if;

        when S1 => if CYCLES = '5' then 
                        MAINGR <= '0' after 5 ns;
                        MAINYE <= '1' after 5 ns;               
                        NEXT_STATE <= S2 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINGR | FARMRE for 5 sec
                        MAINGR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                    end if;

        when S2 => if CYCLES = '5' then                         MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;               
                        NEXT_STATE <= S3 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINYE | FARMRE for 5 sec
                        MAINYE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                    end if;

        when S3 => if CYCLES = '2' then 
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMYE <= '1' after 5 ns;               
                        NEXT_STATE <= S4 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | FARMRE for 2 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                    end if;

        when S4 => if CYCLES = '2' then 
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMGR <= '1' after 5 ns;           
                        NEXT_STATE <= S5 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | FARMRE | FARMYE for 2 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMYE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                    end if;

        when S5 => if CYCLES = '30' then 
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMYE <= '1' after 5 ns;           
                        NEXT_STATE <= S6 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | FARMGR for 30 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMGR <= '1' after 5 ns;   
                    end if; 

        when S6 => if CYCLES = '5' then 
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;           
                        NEXT_STATE <= S7 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | FARMYE for 5 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMYE <= '1' after 5 ns;   
                    end if;

        when S7 => if CYCLES = '2' then 
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        MAINYE <= '1' after 5 ns;   
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;       
                        NEXT_STATE <= S8 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | FARMRE for 2 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;       
                    end if;

        when S8 => if CYCLES = '2' then 
                        MAINGR <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;           
                        NEXT_STATE <= S0 after 5 ns;
                        SCLR <= '1';
                    else                                -- MAINRE | MAINYE | FARMRE for 2 sec
                        MAINRE <= '1' after 5 ns;
                        MAINYE <= '1' after 5 ns;   
                        FARMRE <= '1' after 5 ns;       
                    end if;

end process AMP_KOMB;
end FUNKTION;
```

While compiling the code in **Modelsim PE Student** I get the following error:

```
No feasible entries for infix operator "="
```

After trying many different libraries I can't find any solution to fix this error. I guess it's a problem with the wrong library or the wrong use of the "=" operator.

Here is the full error report from Modelsim:

```
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(68): No feasible entries for infix operator "=".
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(68): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(78): No feasible entries for infix operator "=".
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(78): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(87): No feasible entries for infix operator "=".
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(87): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(98): No feasible entries for infix operator "=".
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(98): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(109): near "'": syntax error
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(114): near "else": expecting END or WHEN
** Error: [...]/AMPSTR.vhdl(117): near "if": expecting PROCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an

```
    end case;
```

right before

```
end process AMP_KOMB;
```

You're using the wrong numeric package, because you're using bit types you should be using numeric_bit.  You shouldn't be mixing std_logic_unsigned and numeric_xxx:

```
library ieee;
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
```

The array length of `CYCLES` is 5, the index range `(4 downto 0)`.  The acceptable literals for use with it should be bit strings:

```
    when S1 => if CYCLES = '5' then
```

should be:

```
    when S1 => if CYCLES = "00101" then
```

etc. (every place CYCLES is evaluated).  Note that `'30'` isn't a character literal, thirty in a bit string literal is `"11110"`.

Fix all those and your VHDL design specification analyzes and elaborates.  Without writing a test bench I didn't simulate it.

And after seeing Brian's answer it's worth pointing out that numeric_bit also has a type declaration for unsigned along with associated operators.

Comment: Thank you David! This helped me a lot and the explanation was very good to understand what I actually did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In `if CYCLES = '5' then` what do you expect to happen?

`CYCLES` is an UNSIGNED. Whether it is a `numeric_std.unsigned` or some other kind of UNSIGNED from that other non-standard library, I cannot tell, but I would recommend only using the `numeric_std` library.

`'5'` in this context is a character literal, unlike `5` which is an integer literal. The compiler apparently can't find an equality operator between UNSIGNED and character literal, according to the error message.

In `if B1 = '1' then`, `'1'` could be either a character literal or a bit literal; both are visible, but only one makes sense (has an equality operator defined for it) so the compiler has no problem with this expression.

Comment: Also thank you Brian thanks to your answer and David's I was able to get the code running.

Answer (score 0):

There are some addition issues which are not addressed by David and Brian in before:

- Your current state signal should have a default assignment, because it's mapped to a register.
- your signal `SCLR` has multiple drivers. Only one process should assign values to a signal. If needed otherwise, implement a 'communication protocol' between these two processes.
- You are using an enum type for the state names instead of an integer (that's good), so please choose proper enum member names to enhance readability of your code :)